# RadioListTile not found in test

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

I am having trouble with a test where I am trying to see if tapping a `RadioListTile` works. Simply looking the element `byType` with finder, doesn't find it even though the parent widget and the list tiles are displayed in the emulator. I really can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The widget tree is as follows:

```
RadioQuestion 
   | QuestionText
   | RadioChoices
      | RadioListTile
```

```
class RadioChoices extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<RadioQuestionModel>(
        builder: (context, model, child) => Column(
              // debugPrint(model.choices) here shows data.
              children: model.choices
                  .map((e) => RadioListTile(
                        title: e,
                        value: model.choices.indexOf(e),
                        groupValue: model.selectedIndex,
                        onChanged: (value) => model.onChanged(value),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ));
  }
}
```

```
testWidgets('Displays choices', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: RadioQuestion(questions[0]))));

    var finder = find.byType(RadioChoices);
    expect(finder, findsOneWidget);

    finder = find.byType(RadioListTile);
    expect(finder,
        findsNWidgets(questions[0].possibleChoices.length)); // This fails, 0 widgets found.
  });
```

```
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly 4 matching nodes in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "RadioListTile<dynamic>" (ignoring offstage
widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but some were expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the List to an array of `RadioListTile`s fixed it:

```
children: <RadioListTile>[]
                ..addAll(model.choices.map((e) => RadioListTile(
                      title: e,
                      value: model.choices.indexOf(e),
                      groupValue: model.selectedIndex,
                      onChanged: (value) => model.onChanged(value),
                    )))
```